# jquery: capturing show / hide event of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div called MyDiv and I have some code that hides and shows the div. I also have two functions, called functionA and functionB that I want to run respectively on the show and the hide event associated with MyDiv. I DO NOT want to call functionA and functionB from the code that shows and hides the div!

Is this even possible? If so, how is is done.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery.hook() : http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/event-handling

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the plugin?